# In which group should store all the images used in the project

Tags: iphone

In which group should store all the images used in the project. Resources group is to store the icon files. Should i create other sources group folder to store rest of all the images used in the project or somewhere else?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It doesn't matter. iOS uses a flat directory by default. By the way, "Resources group is to store icon files" is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups in Xcode (the yellow folders) can be organized any way you like. If you want separate groups for icons, other images, or whatever else, you're free to create them. (You can even have groups map to different directories in your source filesystem.)

By default, everything in such groups will go into the same place in your built app bundle. It's convenient to keep it that way, since it makes APIs like `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` simple to use -- just pass the name of your image file and you're done.